# Notation for a vector with constant equal components of arbitrary dimension

Tags: notation, vectors

Is there a standard notation to specify vectors of the form $(c,c,\ldots,c)$, where $c$ is some constant?, e.g. suppose I have the vector $(c,c,c,c,c)$ which has 5 components. Is there a standard (short hand) way to write such a vector? I am dealing with such vectors of arbitrary size so would like a better way to specify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *standard* notation for this, and the way to go is (in my opinion) to write it as $c \ \vec{\mathbf{1}}$ or $c \ \vec{\mathbf{1}}_n$ where $\vec{\mathbf{1}}$ is the all-one vector (and you explain this). [I do not think there is a real standard notation for the all-one vector even.]

There is also no common notation for the matrix with $c$ on the diagonal, but rather one denotes it as $c \ I_n$ or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $\overrightarrow{(c)}_n$ or $\overrightarrow{c}$.

Comment: Is this standard?

Comment: I think so for we use $R^n$ for $n$ dimension of real number.

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: @pbs As far as I know, there isn't really an accepted standard for the "all one's vector". Some people use $\Bbb 1$, although that's also used for characteristic functions. If you use the arrow notation for vectors, $\vec{1}$ is a good choice. My point here is that there isn't really a standard for a closely-related vector, so I doubt there's one for this. I'd drop the vertical bar and just subscript, but be explicit that you're using this notation, and it should be fine. See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9898/notation-for-the-all-ones-vector)

Comment: Here is the standard I believe. @pbs, have you got it?

Comment: Thanks. I also saw this article http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9898/notation-for-the-all-ones-vector

Comment: That is exactly I told you first time as $\overrightarrow{c}$ for in constant case, normally dimension is ignored.